# what is different Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Microsoft Visual Studio Team System?

Tags: tfs

what is different Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Microsoft Visual Studio Team System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many people think that those are the same,
but one of them is client and other is the server software.
in the server side you have services that applied for systems that we need for developing and software engineering
but in the client side we have UI,IDE only for programming and coding like VS

Comment: I wonder why this answer is down voted without comment. To me it doesn't appear to be wrong. If you know better supply your answer or leave a comment

Answer (score 10):

[TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) is a source control server and associated applications (bug/issue tracker).

> Team Foundation Server (commonly abbreviated to TFS) is a Microsoft product offering source control, data collection, reporting, and project tracking, and is intended for collaborative software development projects.

Visual Studio Team System was the former name of [Visual Studio Application Lifecycle Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Team_System), which is a suite of tools for software development that includes TFS:

> a collection of integrated software development tools developed by Microsoft. These tools include IDEs, source control, work items, collaboration, metrics, and reporting tools.

Comment: when we installed the tfs vsts is installed.we dont want install vsts.